# GetURLSegments return false on List (document library) URL

Tags: api, sharepoint, document-library, geturl

GetURLSegments method of the SharePoint SiteData web service return false when passed the address of a document library.

GetURLSegments return the following for the relative URL's:
FALSE - http://sharepoint.testurl.com/site/subsite/doclibrary
TRUE - http://sharepoint.testurl.com/site/subsite/doclibrary/folder1

When TRUE is returned I get the ID's for the related item. What is strange is when I pass in the root URL of the document library I get FALSE back. The documentation of this web method states the following:

Else if the strURL parameter is a URL of a list within the request site (2)<35>, the protocol server MUST return the GUID of the list. This GUID MUST be enclosed in curly braces ({}).
I confirmed and the casing of the URL is the same as it is on the server.

Why is FALSE returned when I pass in the URL of the document library?
Is there an easy way to determine the ID of the document library if I only have the root URL of the library?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Lists.GetListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) Method to Get the Document Library GUID

The DefaultViewUrl allows you to verify against you URL

Answer (score 0):

What I found was, if, I pass an encoded URL e.g. `http://host/site1/Shared%20Documents/Default.aspx` then it returns false, but, if I pass the raw URL (e.g. with spaces) as `http://host/site1/Shared Documents/Default.aspx` then it returns true alongwith the GUID for containing list. Tested in Sharepoint 2010.